# Opposite function to Normal

Tags: sparse-arrays

Is there any function opposite to Normal? For example, let as say that I have an SparseMatrix A, then,  let as say that for convenience for a certain operation like Packing, I convert it into an Array by doing

```
A=Normal[A];
```

and afterwards, I want A to became an SparseArray again.

Is there anyway to do this without the need to define the matrix A again?

Thanks

Comment: In case there is no such function, a way to solve this problem is to define A_backup =A, then, A=Normal[A] and afterwards A=A_backup.

Comment: `SparseArray[A]`

Comment: @ssch   thankyou!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the background value is 0 just run `SparseArray` on it:

```
sp = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> 1, {100, 100}];
ByteCount[sp]
(* 2152 *)

nrm = Normal[sp];
ByteCount[nrm]
(* 40168 *)

sp2 = SparseArray[nrm];
ByteCount[sp2]
(* 2152 *)
```

If it has another background value do `SparseArray[nrm, Automatic, background]`, if you don't know the background value use the commonest element, which is `First@Commonest[Flatten@nrm]`

Comment: what is the background value?

Comment: @Mencia the default value that is used where nothing else is specified in the `SparseArray` e.g. `SparseArray[Band[{1,1}]->9, {5,5}, Infinity]//Normal//MatrixForm`

Comment: but the best is to specify them as zero right? since zero terms will not take up memory in the SparseArray

Comment: @Mencia Doesn't matter what it is, `SparseArray` only stores information representing position and value for places where the value is not equal to the background value, so for memory use it doesn't matter what the background happens to be. However 0 is very common and is usually what you want (this is why Mathematica assumes you want 0 unless you specify otherwise)

Comment: @Mencia Here's link to some documentation: [`tutorial/SparseArrays-ManipulatingLists`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SparseArrays-ManipulatingLists.html).  It implies what ssch says here, but it's not as clear as this answer. :)

Comment: @ssch  I don't get the same results on V9.0.1 or V10. (`ByteCount /@ {sp, nrm, sp2}` yields `{4720, 80152, 3160}`).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Strange that `Band` gets worse memory than sparsifying(?) a normal array :) Same thing for a larger matrix like 10k x 1k? (I'm on v8.0.4 and get same for sp and sp2)

Comment: @ssch  Yes and the data structure is larger than 8.0.4 (`113008`/`97112` bytes vs. `48952`).  However, `Normal` in 8.0.4 causes unpacking (although the final result is packed) and is really slow compared with V9+.